# How to find where a song occurs in a video audio stream

Tags: video, command-line, music

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04, any software (FOSS or paid) is accepted.

I have a song (mp3) and a video (mp4).

I need to find out where the song starts and ends in the video (Eg. @ 0-60 seconds). Are there any cli tools that can help me with this?

Note that music identification isn't necessary, but would be preferred.

Comment: How about calling https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/Sensifai-Music-Recognition-Trainable-Algorithm/prodview-tnt5od5jzxct2